# Arraylist of an Object inside that object

Tags: java, android

Suppose I use code that looks like this:

```
public class MyObject {
    private int id;
    private ArrayList<MyObject> otherObjects;

    public MyObject(int id) {
        this.id = id;
        ArrayList<MyObject> otherObjects = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
        otherObjects.add(new MyObject(id + 1));
        this.otherObjects = otherObjects;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public ArrayList<MyObject> getOtherObjects() {
        return otherObjects;
    }

    public void setOtherObjects(ArrayList<MyObject> otherObjects) {
        this.otherObjects = otherObjects;
    }
}
```

What pitfalls should I be aware of? My other concern is that if I could make this class Parcellable?

Comment: What are your concerns? There's actually a very common design pattern that uses this: [Composite pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern)

Comment: Looks like infinite recursion where you call 'new MyObject();` inside the constructor.

Comment: @markspace-No it won't be infinite recursion becuse constructor overloading will take place and hence,no chance of recursion even!!!!

Comment: @shekharsuman It's a constructor, not a method. Furthermore, it uses the same signature. So it will definitely run into a stack overflow. Just throw it into ideone and you will see.

Comment: Constructor but not with (int parameter), please correct me if I am wrong! @IngoBürk. OP will be declaring a new constructor in the code to handle object instantiation with no parameters. I guess markspace's logic is incorrect!

Comment: @shekharsuman So I'll just use a static factory there, is that ok?

Comment: @BinoyBabu_Yeah,that seems pretty OK,but take care to see synchronisation issues as mentioned by `Matthew Palsberg` in the below answer.

Comment: @shekharsuman I'll use final modifiers for all fields, and do away with setters, so that issue will be resolved right?

Comment: Setters is indeed a good idea to remove all kind of stack overflows and all other errors. Also, making fields `final` depends on the need of the project,you may or mayn't. BTW,I don't find any serious truble even in non-final fields!

Comment: @shekharsuman Okay, thanks, any issues when I make this class Parcellable?

Comment: @shekharsuman The constructor in the code has an `int` parameter and he calls the constructor with this parameter plus one. Again, take this code, throw it on ideone and call `new MyObject(1)` and watch it explode. Or just [click here](http://ideone.com/AYbb79).

Comment: @IngoBürk-OK,I missed this line while reading the question. I can't believe but it was not in the first glance. Can't believe this,but,you're extremely right!

Comment: @BinoyBabu-See above comment by `IgnoBurk`,your code will throw stack-overflow error! Also,parcelable is in Android I guess,but that is more efficient than Serialiable and also causes less garbage generation!

Answer (score 4):

If you run it with different threads you have data races since you have no lock on your global variables.

Answer (score 1):

Add to what **Mathew Palsberg** said

**ArrayList** is unsynchronized, making them, therefore, not thread safe.

> Note that this implementation is not synchronized. **If multiple threads
>   access an ArrayList instance concurrently, and at least one of the
>   threads modifies the list structurally, it must be synchronized
>   externally**. (A structural modification is any operation that adds or
>   deletes one or more elements, or explicitly resizes the backing array;
>   merely setting the value of an element is not a structural
>   modification.) This is typically accomplished by synchronizing on some
>   object that naturally encapsulates the list. If no such object exists,
>   the list should be "wrapped" using the Collections.synchronizedList
>   method. **This is best done at creation time, to prevent accidental
>   unsynchronized access to the list:**
>
> **List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList(...));**

source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html